# How to use moment.js to subtract two times and compare it to a number of minutes

Tags: javascript, ruby, momentjs

I am working on implementing a JS function to mirror a function that I have in my Ruby code.

**The Ruby Code:**

```
def autoextending?
  online_only? && ((actual_end_time - Time.now) <= autoextend_increment.minutes)
end
```

**The JS Code:**

```
item.autoextending = function() {
  var self = this;
  var end_time = moment(self.actual_end_time);
  return (self.online_only && self.status == "accepting_bids" && ((end_time - moment()) <= self.autoextend_increment*60));
};
```

A little information:

- self.autoextend_increment will return a number such as 5 which represents a number of minutes.
- I need the evaluation of `(end_time - moment())` to return the difference as a number of seconds so that I can compare it to the `autoextend_increment` properly

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're dealing with minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Are you asking how to convert between each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment` uses [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) under the hood, which as a raw value is represented as time in milliseconds since epoch. So right away we know that arithmetic from `moment` will yield values in milliseconds:

```
item.autoextending = function() {
    var self = this;
    var end_time = moment(self.actual_end_time);
    return (self.online_only && self.status == "accepting_bids" && (((end_time - moment()) / (1000 * 60)) <= self.autoextend_increment));
};
```

`((end_time - moment()) / (1000 * 60))` will give you a value in minutes (1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in a minute).

You said `self.autoextend_increment` is already in minutes, so no additional arithmetic is needed. If you really want to compare in seconds, you can: `((end_time - moment()) / 1000) <= self.autoextend_increment * 60`

You could have also written your conversion as `(end_time - moment()) / 6000` but I broke down the figures for demonstration purposes.